# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OContext

Tags: r, apache-spark, h2o, sparklyr

```
library(rsparkling)
library(sparklyr)
library(h2o)
test <- as_h2o_frame(sc, partitions$test, strict_version_check = FALSE)
```

the error is following:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OContext
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
……
```

Could you help me solve this question? thanks.

Comment: How do you start sparkr? How do you "install" h2o library?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this arises when you installed h2o before spark. Sparkling is not working with the very last version of h2o.
You need to clear `h2o` installation and choose the one corresponding to your `rsparkling` installation. The table of correspondence is here: https://github.com/h2oai/rsparkling/blob/master/README.md
To uninstall library h2o:

```
# detach loaded libraries
  detach("package:rsparkling", unload = TRUE)
  if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) {detach("package:h2o", unload = TRUE)}
  if (isNamespaceLoaded("h2o")) { unloadNamespace("h2o") }
# remove h2o from your installation
  remove.packages("h2o", lib = .libPaths()[1])
```

And re-install it from repository with sparkling compatibility:

```
# install last h2o for which sparkling is available
  install.packages("h2o", type = "source",
    repos = "http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-tverberg/2/R")
```

If needed, install the last spark version:

```
# spark_available_versions()
spark_install(version = "2.1.0", hadoop_version = "2.7")
```

Reload your R session or close/open it and try again to connect to spark:

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.1.0")
```

Comment: thanks. But there is another question. mtcars_h2o <- as_h2o_frame(sc, mtcars_tbl)
Error in h2o.init(ip = ip, port = port, strict_version_check = strict_version_check,  : 
  Version mismatch! H2O is running version 3.10.4.8 but h2o-R package is version 3.10.3.2.
         Install the matching h2o-R version from - http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-ueno/8/index.html

Comment: You need to clear `h2o` installation and choose the one corresponding to your `rsparkling` installation. The table of correspondence is here: https://github.com/h2oai/rsparkling/blob/master/README.md